# Simon says HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, community-challenge, simon-says

Here's a little game written in HTML5 using bleeding edge audio.  Since I don't do much HTML5 or Javascript, I'm particularly interested in:

- **Structure** Is this a reasonable way to structure the Javascript?  Should I encapsulate everything in an object?
- **Compatibility** I believe the older versions of Internet Explorer won't work with this.  Are there other issues with modern browsers?

The in-game instructions are terse, but the keys <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>f</kbd> correspond to upper left, upper right, lower left and lower right quadrants respectively. Alternatively, you can use the mouse. <s>It may also work with a touchscreen -- I'd be interested in learning if it does.</s> It works with at least some touchscreens (Windows 8 and iPhone), but I'd be interested in learning of touchscreens where it does *not* seem to work.

```js
var litcolors = ['red', 'yellow', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen'];
var colors = ['darkred', 'darkorange', 'darkblue', 'darkgreen'];
var ctx, innerRadius, outerRadius;
var states = [ false, false, false, false ];
var keys = [ 74, 75, 70, 68 ];
var notes = [ 261.626, 329.628, 391.995, 523.251 ];
var sequence = [];
var seqitem = 0;
var c;
var turn = 0;
var timeout;

function instructions() {
    alert("After the computer shows a sequence,\ntry to reproduce it.\nYou can use the keys kldf or the mouse");
}
function init() {
    c = document.getElementById('simon');
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    paintToy(-1);
    instructions();
    c.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(c, evt);
        var quadrant = getQuadrant(mousePos);
        if (turn == 1) {
            tryMove(quadrant);
        }
    }, false);    

    c.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
        paintToy(-1);
    }, false);    

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
        paintToy(-1);
    }, false);    

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
        var quadrant = getQuadrantKey(evt.keyCode);
        if (turn == 1) {
            tryMove(quadrant);
        }
    }, false);

    computerTurn();
}
// Temporary workaround until AudioContext is standardized 
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
osc.type = 'triangle';
osc.start(0);
var score = 0;

function beep(frequency, duration, after) {
    if (typeof after != "function") {
        after = function () {};
    }
    osc.frequency.value = +frequency;
    osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    setTimeout(function () {
        osc.disconnect();
        after();
    }, +duration);
}
function paintToy(litquadrant) {
    writeMessage(c,10,25, ""+score);
    writeMessage(c,400,490, "Simon");
    outerRadius = c.width * 0.45;
    innerRadius = c.width * 0.05;
    ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        states[i] = (litquadrant == i);
        slice(i);
    }
    ctx.translate(-c.width / 2, -c.height / 2);
}
function slice(quadrant) {
    ctx.rotate(quadrant * Math.PI/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(-5,-5,innerRadius,Math.PI, 3*Math.PI/2 );
    ctx.lineTo(-5,-outerRadius-5);
    ctx.arc(-5,-5,outerRadius, 3*Math.PI/2,Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    if (states[quadrant]) {
        ctx.fillStyle = litcolors[quadrant];
    } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[quadrant];
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-quadrant * Math.PI/2);
}
function getQuadrant(mousePos) {
    var quadrant = 0;
    if (mousePos.y > c.width/2) {
        quadrant = 3;
    }
    if (mousePos.x > c.width/2) {
        if (quadrant == 3) {
            quadrant = 2;
        } else {
            quadrant++;
        }
    }
    return quadrant;
}
function writeMessage(canvas, x, y, message) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(x, y-30, canvas.width, 200);
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, x, y);
}
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: Math.round((evt.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*canvas.width),
        y: Math.round((evt.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*canvas.height)
    };
}
function getQuadrantKey(keycode) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (keys[i] == keycode) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
function sound(quadrant) {
    if ((quadrant < 0) || (quadrant > 3))
        return;
    beep(notes[quadrant],200, false);
}
function tryMove(quadrant) {
    paintToy(quadrant);
    if (sequence[seqitem++] == quadrant) {
        sound(quadrant);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if (seqitem == sequence.length) {
            score++;
            turn = 0;
            setTimeout(computerTurn, 1000);
        } else {
            timeout = setTimeout(lose, 5000);
        }
    } else {
        lose();
    }
}
function computerPlay() {
    sound(sequence[seqitem]);
    paintToy(sequence[seqitem++]);
    setTimeout(clear, 200);
    if (seqitem < sequence.length) {
        setTimeout(computerPlay, 1000);
    } else {
        turn = 1;
        humanTurn();
    }
}
function computerTurn() {
    sequence.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 4)));
    seqitem = 0;
    computerPlay();
}
function clear() {
    beep(0, 200, false);
    paintToy(-1);
}
function humanTurn() {
    seqitem = 0;
    timeout = setTimeout(lose, 5000);
}
function lose() {
    turn = -1;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    beep(155.563, 200, function(){alert("Sorry, you lose!")});
}
function losemsg() {
    alert("Sorry, you lose!");
}

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simon</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="simon" width="500" height="500"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.  How sad.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't really expect it to, but it doesn't work on mobile chrome. Looking forward to checking it out on my PC.

Comment: @RubberDuck: should be supported as of mobile Chrome 28 via webkit according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) but there may be incompatibilities in the API.  The [latest draft](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) is only a few days old.

Comment: Simon says: ask this question on codereview

Comment: Rest in peace, [Mr. Ralph H. Baer](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/08/business/ralph-h-baer-dies-inventor-of-odyssey-first-system-for-home-video-games.html?_r=0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, bravo! It's very fun and highly nostalgic. I may or may not have <strike>forced</strike> encouraged my children to play it well past their bedtime.

As to the structure, in 2014, it is absolutely recommended that you encapsulate your game inside a module. This ensures that it's portable, that it doesn't cause conflicts in the global namespace, and (from a self-discipline perspective) it will benefit from a bit more code organization and thinking about things like DRY, scoping, subclasses, etc.

So some general pseudocode from a more OO-style would be:

```
SimonGame {

    Oscillator {
        Type
        Frequency
        Start()
        Disconnect()
        Beep()
   }

    Canvas {
        WriteMessage()
        Paint()
        Quadrants
            Quadrant
                Color
                LitColor
                State
   }

    Guess()

    Init(options)   
}
```

That's just a rough start, but the general idea would be to call things like Canvas.Paint() and Oscillator.Beep(), etc. rather than your global functions.

You might also want take a document element or ID in your Init() method arguments so the user can pass in the canvas they want to "simonize".

Comment: That's a good hint, thanks.  Is [this link](http://jsmodules.io/) a good place to start to teach myself how to create modules in Javascript?

Comment: Yep, that covers the gist of it, and certainly enough for the purposes of this game.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @KyleHale's useful answer, I've improved the original code.  Still not great but definitely better.  I have another idea to implement a new feature, but if I do that it will be in a new question.

```js
var Simon = (function () {
    var simon = {};

    var Oscillator = (function () {
        var mysound = {};
        var notes = [ 261.626, 329.628, 391.995, 523.251 ];
        // Temporary workaround until AudioContext is standardized 
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        var osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        osc.type = 'triangle';
        osc.start(0);

        mysound.sound = function (quadrant) {
            if ((quadrant < 0) || (quadrant > 3))
                return;
            beep(notes[quadrant],200, false);
        }
        mysound.silence = function () {
            beep(0, 200, false);
        }
        mysound.losebeep = function (after) {
            beep(155.563, 200, after);
        }
        var beep = function (frequency, duration, after) {
            if (typeof after != "function") {
                after = function () {};
            }
            osc.frequency.value = +frequency;
            osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            setTimeout(function () {
                osc.disconnect();
                after();
            }, +duration);
        }
        return mysound;
    })();

    var GameBoard = (function () {
        var game = {};
        var litcolors = ['red', 'yellow', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen'];
        var colors = ['darkred', 'darkorange', 'darkblue', 'darkgreen'];
        var innerRadius, outerRadius;
        var states = [ false, false, false, false ];
        var keys = [ 74, 75, 70, 68 ];
        var sequence = [];
        var seqitem = 0;
        var turn = 0;
        var timeout;
        var score = 0;
        var ctx;
        var c;

        game.setCanvas = function (canvas) {
            c = canvas;
            ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            return c;
        }

        game.paintToy = function (litquadrant) {
            writeMessage(c,10,25, ""+score);
            writeMessage(c,400,490, "Simon");
            outerRadius = c.width * 0.45;
            innerRadius = c.width * 0.05;
            ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                states[i] = (litquadrant == i);
                slice(i);
            }
            ctx.translate(-c.width / 2, -c.height / 2);
        }
        var slice = function (quadrant) {
            ctx.rotate(quadrant * Math.PI/2);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(-5,-5,innerRadius,Math.PI, 3*Math.PI/2 );
            ctx.lineTo(-5,-outerRadius-5);
            ctx.arc(-5,-5,outerRadius, 3*Math.PI/2,Math.PI, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            if (states[quadrant]) {
                ctx.fillStyle = litcolors[quadrant];
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = colors[quadrant];
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.rotate(-quadrant * Math.PI/2);
        }
        game.getQuadrant = function (mousePos) {
            var quadrant = 0;
            if (mousePos.y > c.width/2) {
                quadrant = 3;
            }
            if (mousePos.x > c.width/2) {
                if (quadrant == 3) {
                    quadrant = 2;
                } else {
                    quadrant++;
                }
            }
            return quadrant;
        }
        var writeMessage = function (canvas, x, y, message) {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(x, y-30, canvas.width, 200);
            context.font = '18pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'black';
            context.fillText(message, x, y);
        }
        game.getMousePos = function (canvas, evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: Math.round((evt.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*canvas.width),
                y: Math.round((evt.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*canvas.height)
            };
        }
        game.getQuadrantKey = function (keycode) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (keys[i] == keycode) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        game.tryMove = function (quadrant) {
            game.paintToy(quadrant);
            if (sequence[seqitem++] == quadrant) {
                Oscillator.sound(quadrant);
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                if (seqitem == sequence.length) {
                    score++;
                    turn = 0;
                    setTimeout(game.computerTurn, 1000);
                } else {
                    timeout = setTimeout(lose, 5000);
                }
            } else {
                lose();
            }
        }
        game.isHumanTurn = function () {
            return turn == 1;
        }
        var computerPlay = function () {
            Oscillator.sound(sequence[seqitem]);
            game.paintToy(sequence[seqitem++]);
            setTimeout(clear, 200);
            if (seqitem < sequence.length) {
                setTimeout(computerPlay, 1000);
            } else {
                turn = 1;
                humanTurn();
            }
        }
        game.computerTurn = function () {
            sequence.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 4)));
            seqitem = 0;
            computerPlay();
        }
        var clear = function () {
            Oscillator.silence();
            game.paintToy(-1);
        }
        var humanTurn = function () {
            seqitem = 0;
            timeout = setTimeout(lose, 5000);
        }
        var lose = function () {
            turn = -1;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            Oscillator.losebeep(function(){alert("Sorry, you lose!")});
        }
        return game;
    })();

    var instructions = function () {
        alert("After the computer shows a sequence,\ntry to reproduce it.\nYou can use the keys dfjk or the mouse");
    }
    simon.run = function(canvas) {
        c = GameBoard.setCanvas(canvas);
        GameBoard.paintToy(-1);
        instructions();
        c.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
            var mousePos = GameBoard.getMousePos(c, evt);
            var quadrant = GameBoard.getQuadrant(mousePos);
            if (GameBoard.isHumanTurn()) {
                GameBoard.tryMove(quadrant);
            }
        }, false);    

        c.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
            GameBoard.paintToy(-1);
        }, false);    

        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
            GameBoard.paintToy(-1);
        }, false);    

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
            var quadrant = GameBoard.getQuadrantKey(evt.keyCode);
            if (GameBoard.isHumanTurn()) {
                GameBoard.tryMove(quadrant);
            }
        }, false);

        GameBoard.computerTurn();
    }

    return simon;
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simon</title>
</head>
<body onload="Simon.run(simon)">
<canvas id="simon" width="500" height="500"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.  How sad.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```